# How to perform a beforeUnload event on React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I´m trying to use beforeUnload event on react to perform an action before tab closes or user refreshes the page, the event never fires... I´m using the effect on App component.

```
import "./styles/global.css";
import Home from "./sections/Home";
import Header from "./components/Header";
import Footer from "./components/Footer";
import { useEffect } from "react";

function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    const onBeforeUnload = (ev) => {
      ev.returnValue = "Anything you wanna put here!";
      return "Anything here as well, doesn't matter!";
    };

    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", onBeforeUnload);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("beforeunload", onBeforeUnload);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
        <Header />
        <Home />
        <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import "./styles/global.css";
import Home from "./sections/Home";
import Header from "./components/Header";
import Footer from "./components/Footer";
import { useEffect } from "react";

function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    const onBeforeUnload = (ev) => {
      
      //#############     
      console.log("SOME CODE HERE");
      //#############

      ev.returnValue = "Anything you wanna put here!";
      return "Anything here as well, doesn't matter!";
    };

    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", onBeforeUnload);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("beforeunload", onBeforeUnload);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
        <Header />
        <Home />
        <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but still not working ... i don't know what is the problem

Comment: That's really interesting, can you post the entire jsx file?

Comment: I posted the code on the APP.jsx file so you can see  what i have...

Comment: Maybe the problem is that i'm not understanding the purpose of the beforeUnload event,  couse as i mentioned... i want to execute some code just before the page reloads. Is there any way to do that without using this?

Comment: I edited my answer. this code is working for me, it executes the console.log when the user tries to refresh or close the page. You don't want the confirm dialog to open?

Comment: I tested without the return part, and the console.log was executed also, what code are you trying to execute before?

Comment: Well I haven't implemented it yet as I was testing this... I want my page to reload on top. The way I currently have it, every time I do a reload, the browser is updated to the current position, the problem is that I have the intersection observer implemented... and well, I think you understand... That's why I was thinking something like scrollTo(0,0) with beforeUnload event.

Answer (score 1):

make the `useEffect` fires on any update (by removing the empty dependancy),
then put inside any code you want it to be exexuted before closing the tab or refresh.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", () => {
    // any code you want
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

The magic ingredient that you are missing is `preventDefault`. As Mozilla [explains](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event):

> **Window: beforeunload event**
>
> The beforeunload event is fired when the current window, contained document, and associated resources are about to be unloaded. The document is still visible and the event is still cancelable at this point.
>
> The main use case for this event is to trigger a browser-generated confirmation dialog that asks users to confirm if they really want to leave the page when they try to close or reload it, or navigate somewhere else. This is intended to help prevent loss of unsaved data.
>
> The dialog can be triggered in the following ways:
>
> - Calling the event object's preventDefault() method.
> - Setting the event object's returnValue property to a non-empty string value or any other truthy value.
> - Returning any truthy value from the event handler function, e.g. return "string". Note that this only works when the function is attached via the onbeforeunload property, not the addEventListener() method. This behavior is consistent across modern versions of Firefox, Safari, and Chrome.
>
> The last two mechanisms are legacy features; best practice is to trigger the dialog by invoking preventDefault() on the event object, while also setting returnValue to support legacy cases.

So let's say you have a boolean variable `isDirty` - a boolean. The variable is `true` when a form is "dirty" (it has unsaved content) and `false` otherwise. So you can write a `useEffect` that shows a dialog to the user if they try to close the window when the form has unsaved content.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const onBeforeUnload = (ev: Event) => {
      if (isDirty) {
        ev.preventDefault();
      }
      ev.returnValue = isDirty;
      return isDirty;
    };
    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', onBeforeUnload);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', onBeforeUnload);
    };
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);
```

Note: `returnValue` attribute is deprecated, so you might get an underline through it in VSCode with ESLint enabled.

Answer (score -1):

I have already make it work thanks !!... Clearly i wasn´t getting the pop up when reloading page (wich is a misterious thing), but the code before the return executes perfectly.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).